# Similarity about unitary matrices

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, finite-groups, unitary-representations

Suppose $G_1, \ldots, G_k$ are unitary, Hermitian, and anti-commuting matrices, and assume the same for $F_1, \ldots, F_k$. Suppose these matrices are similar, i.e. there exists $T \in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that
$$
G_i = T^{-1} F_i T
$$
for all $i \in [k]$. Does there exist $V \in U_n$, where $U_n$ is the group of unitary matrices, such that
$$
G_i = V^{-1} F_i V
$$
for all $i \in [k]$?

**Added later:**
Generally, let $\pi, \sigma : G \to U_n(\mathbb{C})$ be two unitary representations of a finite group. Suppose $\pi$, $\sigma$ are equivalent, i.e. there exists $T \in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $T \pi(g) = \sigma(g) T$ for all $g \in G$. Are $\pi$ and $\sigma$ unitarily equivalent, that is, there exists $T' \in U_n$ such that $T' \pi = \sigma T'$?

Comment: Motivation? Ideas already tried? Context?

Comment: More generally, if we have two equivalent (in the sense of similar) unitary representations (not necessarily irreducible) of a group G, is it true that they are unitarily similar?

I am not sure whether it is a well-known conclusion in representation theory.

Comment: I can not see a solution even when $k = 1$ ....

Comment: The motivation is to investigate the representation of a group $\mathcal{G}_k$, which has generators $g_1, \ldots, g_k$ such that $g_i^2 = -1$ and $g_i g_j = - g_j g_i$.

Comment: It seems to be a simple application of polar decomposition.

Comment: I am not keen on answering anonymous users (anonymous != pseudonymous), but, working over ${\mathbb C}$: If two unitary matrices are similar then they have the same eigenvalues, counting multiplicity. Also, every unitary matrix is unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix. So the answer to this question (and your earlier version) would seem to be "yes".

Comment: This is in response to your request below: "I appreciate if you could point me to a concrete place on Internet or on a book." Well, I appreciate it if you give me some indication of what level you are studying at. Otherwise I might as well be writing mumbo-jumbo for all the good it would do. Why not type "polar decomposition" into your favourite search engine?

Comment: Let me also link to David Roberts's comment on your earlier question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/107645/a-question-about-similarity-of-unitary-matrices-closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this question deserves an answer which doesn't use decomposition into irreducible representations. Let $\pi$ and $\sigma$ be equivalent unitary representations. If $T$ intertwines, then so does $T^{\ast}$, because $\pi(g^{-1})=\pi(g)^{\ast}$ (same for $\sigma$). Now we can conclude that $|T|=\sqrt{T^{\ast}T}$ is also an intertwiner. Finally, $T|T|^{-1}$ is the unitary we need.

Comment: Nice. I still am partial to an argument that just uses lin algebra at 1st/2nd course level, though

Comment: It seems that there is some problem... Using the notations above, $T \pi=\sigma T$, and $\pi T^* = (\pi^{-1})^* T^* = (T \pi^{-1})^* = (\sigma^{-1} T)^* = T^* \sigma$. Thus, both $T$ and $(T^*)^{−1}$ intertwines. 

$T|T|^{−1}$ is unitary. However, I can't see why $T|T|^{−1}π=\sigma T|T|^{−1}$, which amounts to $\pi|T|=|T|\pi$. Why this is true?

Comment: $|T|$ is a norm limit of polynomials in $T^{\ast}T$ and the latter operator can be easily seen to commute with $\pi$.

Comment: Could you tell me the definition of "norm limit of polynomials"? I haven't seen it before. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, $T^* T$ commutes with $\pi$. So, every polynomial in $T^* T$ commutes with $\pi$. What is the norm limit of polynomial? In my impression, norm of a matrix is defined to be a non-negative real number, not a matrix.

Comment: Dear unknown (google) - this is functional calculus for positive matrices/operators; see any reasonable introduction to operator theory, or even some linear algebra textbooks

Comment: I appreciate if you could point me to a concrete place on Internet or on a book. Thank you.

Comment: I believe Mateusz means that there exist polynomials $p_n$ such that the sequence $p_n(T^*T)$ converges to the matrix $|T|$ with respect to the operator norm. Again, since you only seem to care about the matrix case, there are ways of doing this just using the spectral theorem for normal matrices, which is in itself one of the tools often used to construct these polynomials.

Comment: So, you mean we could expand square root of a matrix in polynomial just like Taylor series for real functions?

I am thinking of a way to show this only by matrix.

Comment: By spectral theorem for normal matrices, $T^*T = U D U^*$, where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal. Then, $|T| = U D^{1/2} U^*$. Yes, we could express $|T|$ in terms of $T^*T$ by Taylor series $\sqrt{1 + (D-1)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{(1-2n)(n!)^2(4^n)}(D-1)^n$. Is there any direct way to show show $|T|$ commutes with $\pi$ given $T^*T$ commuting with $\pi$?

Comment: The Taylor series is not the way to go. Google "Weierstrass approximation theorem" and then I suggest you take further questions to http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Or, better still: apply Lagrange interpolation to find a polynomial $p$ such that $p(D)=D^{1/2}$...

Answer (score 0):

Two similar unitary representations are always unitarily similar if they are irreducible. An isomorphism $V_1 \to V_2$ pulls back the unitary metric on $V_2$ to a unitary metric on $V_1$. To make this unitary, we need to change that metric into the original metric on $V_1$ through a $G$-equivariant map $V_1\to V_1$. But any two unitary metrics on a representation are related by a $G$-equivariant map, so this is always possible.

Comment: If two irreducible unitary representations are similar, then T would be a scalar multiple of the identity by Schur's lemma. What happens if two representations are not irreducible? Did you mean that through a $G$-equivariant map $V_1 \to V_1$, we can make $T$ unitary? And how to find such a $G$-equivariant map?

Comment: We can write a unitary metric as a unitary matrix with one row or column for each irreducible subrepresentation, where all entries that correspond to two non-isomorphic representations are zero. Similarly, a G-equivariant map is a matrix where all entries that correspond to two non-isomorphi representations are zero. G-equivariant maps act by simultaneous left multiplication and right conjugate multiplication. The only invariant preserved by this action is the signature of each block. Unitary metrics are always positive-definite, so this is the same for both metrics.

Comment: In other words, you take a square root.

Comment: Did you mean that the answer is "yes" for irreducible representations, and the answer may be "no" for the others?

Comment: No, I mean it's true in general. 